# proving that the inclusions $i:X \to CX$, $j:Y \to C_f$, $j':Y \to M_f$ have the homotopy extension property

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, retraction

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $f:X \to Y$ a continuous map. 
I want to show that the inclusions $i: X \to CX, \: j:Y \to C_f, \: j':Y \to M_f$ all have the homotopy extension property. Where $CX$ denotes the cone over $X$, $C_f$ the mapping cone, and $M_f$ the mapping cylinder.

My ideas:

1. I read that $CX$ has the structure of a relative CW-complex over $X$. Which would already give me the first homotopy-extension property. But I don't understand why this is the case. Since we would have to have uncountably many copies of $X$ to get $X \times [0,1]$
2. I already know that the maps $i,j$ and $j'$ are neighbourhood deformation retracts. But I don't think that this is equivalent in general to HEP.
3. $Y$ should be homotopy-equivalent to $M_f$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: To begin, do you know how to prove that the inclusion $X\hookrightarrow X\times [0,1]$ at time $0$ has the HEP.

Comment: Yes, I can find a retract of $X \times I^2$ to $X \times I \times \{0\} \cup X \times \{0\} \times I$, given by $(x,s,t) \mapsto (x, s - \min\{s,t\}, t - \min\{s,t\})$

Comment: Good! You're 90% of the way there. The mapping cylinder and the cone both contain neighourhoods of $X$ which are homeomorphic to $X\times I$.

Comment: For the cone, yes. But $Y$ is attached to the mapping cylinder. So maybe neighbourhoods of $X$ contain parts of $Y$. Then I don't see the argument. (Maybe I am missing something). But for the cone we can extend the homotopy to a nbhd. of $X$. But why to the whole cone ? $X \times \{1\}$ is giving me trouble. Because the homotopy we get on $X \times I$ is maybe not well defined after taking the quotient by $X \times \{1\}$.

Comment: For the cone you can modify the retraction you wrote above, or you can choose an NDR structure for $X\hookrightarrow X\times I$ and modify it accordingly. For the making cylinder, I didn't realise you were asking about $Y$. This is even easier: the pushout of a cofibration is a cofibration.

Comment: We didn't have cofibrations in the lecture. How could I modify this retraction ?